# what is proper java collection with unique element (like set) with get element feature

Tags: java, collections, set, hashset

I Used Java `HashSet` for storing unique elements but now I want to retrieve element but HashSet does not has something like that, Here is what I want for my problem:

**for my usecase `LinkInfo` hashCode() and equals() methods do not use LinkInfo.id field** I want to get linkinfo instance from set and update all of its' fields except id field that should be from old instance

```
Set<LinkInfo> fooSet = new HashSet<>()

public void updateFoo(LinkInfo linkInfo) {

    LinkInfo temp = fooSet.get(linkInfo);


    linkInfo.setId(temp.getId());

    // now update set
    fooSet.remove(linkInfo)
    fooSet.add(linkInfo)

    }
```

Comment: Mate, may be I am not getting your question. Please elaborate what is happening now and what is that you want.

Comment: As per the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014641/java-retrieving-an-element-from-a-hashset) *If you know what element you want to retrieve, then you already have the element.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than

```
LinkInfo temp = fooSet.get(linkInfo);
```

the below logic is the same as what you seem to want

```
if (fooSet.contains(linkInfo)) {
   temp = linkInfo;
}
```

Comment: He wants to retrieve a specific instance, not some other instance like what you pass into contains, even though they are equal.

Comment: I think even the equal object should meet the requirement, but to get the exact instance, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940635/1262248

Comment: @POrekhov In that case he does not want to use a `Set`

Comment: Indeed he does not want to use a `Set`.  His question is exactly what he should use instead.

Comment: I answered, saying that he should use a map

Comment: I agree, @POrekhov. And I anticipated you by ten minutes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry, did not notice you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're doing this, but to answer the question, yes you can do this, but you should use a map, like so:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    static class Test {
        public int a,b;

        public Test(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Test that = (Test)obj;
            return this.a == that.a && this.b == that.b;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return a ^ b;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Test,Test> map = new HashMap<>();
        Test t = new Test(1,2);
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(t));
        map.put(t, t);
        Test t2 = new Test(1,2);
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(t2));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(map.get(t2)));
    }
}
```

Now you are able to retrieve the instance that you put into that map initially through an instance that is equal to it.

The program printed:

```
475266352
1355531311
475266352
```

on my computer. You can use a HashSet and iterate through it achieving the same result, but it won't be O(1).

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of a logical problem here.  Why should an API that depends on `equals()` provide a method `getElementEqualTo(e)`?  In order to use such a method, you need to present an object that, for the API's purposes, is equivalent to the desired result.  What would be the point of that?

But that doesn't mean you're out of luck.  I think you're saying that your `LinkInfo` class provides `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods suitable for identifying the object you want by means of a different object that you can obtain.  In that case, it sounds like a `HashMap` could serve your purpose.  Just map each key to itself.

```
HashMap<LinkInfo, LinkInfo> infos;

public void updateInfo(LinkInfo linkInfo) {
    LinkInfo temp = infos.remove(linkInfo);

    if (temp != null) {
        linkInfo.setId(temp.getId());
    }

    infos.put(linkInfo, linkInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Scary answer above, but in case you want the exact reference that is stored in the Set instead of an similar `equal` object, you may use below code:

```
public void updateFoo(LinkInfo linkInfo) {

LinkInfo temp = null;
for(LinkInfo curLinkInfo:fooSet) if (curLinkInfo.equals(linkInfo))temp = curLinkInfo;

if(temp!=null)
linkInfo.setId(temp.getId());

// now update set
fooSet.remove(linkInfo)
fooSet.add(linkInfo)

}
```