# How to get() specific element from HashSet? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, hashset

Assume `myHashSet = HashSet<SomeClass>`

where `SomeClass.hashcode() = someField.hashcode()`

How can I return an element with the specified hashcode, i.e:

```
myHashSet.getElementWithHashCode((other as SomeClass).someField.hashcode())
```

`other` and the objects inside the `HashSet` are different objects with different property values except `someField` value. In other words, these two different type of objects have a common field that might have the same value.

It is weird that there is no such function in HashSet. No one needed that before? What is the quickest way around?

Comment: You can search for elements in collections with functions like `find` or `first`. Pass it the criteria as a lambda: `mySet.find { it.hashcode() == other.hashcode() }`.

Comment: @MalteHartwig Yeap. It worked. Actually this is what a `getItem()` function would do inside. So the performance won't be affected I suppose. If you write this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: No, performance will definitely be affected; e.g. if there is no element with the hashcode you want, it will iterate over the entire set.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Right. It is not same with fetching the value directly from the memory with the key. So is there a way to use the hashcode to get the element from the key location?

Comment: I gave the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/get-element.html) could you in your case, it would depends on whether it used `hashCode` or `equals` internally. Some [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014641/java-retrieving-an-element-from-a-hashset) online that have a similar problem are looking for an equals-based solution.

Anyway, you can use built-in functions like `find` or `first` to implement it yourself:

```
fun <E> HashSet<E>.findByHashCode(other: E): E? = firstOrNull { it.hashCode() == other.hashCode() }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard solution; but since [`HashMap.get(key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) specifies that it compares parameter to stored keys (`key.equals(k)`) and not the other way around, you could achieve the desired result with this nasty hack (nasty because it breaks the `equals` contract):

```
class HasHash(private val hash: Int) {
    override fun hashCode() = hash
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = other != null && other.hashCode() == hash
}
```

But even then `HashSet` on JVM doesn't expose the details you need (like [`getElement` in Kotlin/Native](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/get-element.html)), so the only solution I can come up with is

```
val set: HashSet<T> = ...
val map: Map<Any, T> = set.associateBy { it }

fun findByHashCode(hash: Int): T? = map[HasHash(hash)]
```

which needs to iterate over the `set` to construct `map`, but only once, so it can still be useful if you need to find many elements in a single set.

In Kotlin/Native it's just

```
fun <T> HashSet<T>.findByHashCode(hash: Int): T? = getElement(HasHash(hash))
```

Also if there are multiple elements with the desired hashcode in the set you'll just get one of them.

> So you are mapping each item with itself as key? Does it mean that associateby{} automatically takes the hashcode() of the element as key

No. The idea is:

1. Say `set` contains `"a"` (hashcode `1`; not really but assume so for this example), `"b"` (hashcode `1`), and `"c"` (hashcode `2`).
2. Then `map` is `"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c"`.
3. Call `findByHashCode(1) = map[HasHash(1)]`.
4. Hashcode of `HasHash(1)` is `1`, so it looks up the slot containing keys `"a"` and `"b"` (let's say in that order). `HasHash(1).equals("a")` returns `true`, so the value stored with key `"a"` is returned and that's `"a"`.

> or getElement() function automatically checks according to the hashcode of the input element?

What it says is

> > Return the element from the set equal to element, or null if no such element found.

so it should return `"a"` *if* it compares them in order `HasHash(1).equals("a")`.

Comment: Could not understand `(this as HashSet<Any>)[HasHash(hash)]` part. Not sure if I ever seen such a syntax before.

Comment: Which part? `this` is how you refer to the receiver parameter in extension functions, `as` is a cast, `[...]` is syntax sugar for `get` method.

Comment: So you used `get(HasHash(hash))`. But no `get()` method is in the suggestion list for HashSet objects in Android Studio.

Comment: Oops, I was mixing it up with `Map` API. So fixed, but with an additional bad limitation :(

Comment: So you are mapping each item with itself as key? Does it mean that `associateby{}` automatically takes the hashcode() of the element as key or `getElement()` function automatically checks according to the hashcode of the input element? Because the output should be not HasHash(hash) itself but its hashTwin.

Comment: No and no. I explained in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for details. So the functions do their job on equality and we define equality based on `hashcode()`. As you mentioned, turning into map is useful if multiple searches are to be done. In my case single search is enough. But anyway I consider turning the whole set into Map all over the project for its speed and flexibility over HashSet.